# Jquery combobox/autocomplete scroll is not working with slimscroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, combobox, nested, slimscroll

I have a page which is configured with slim scroll plugin.I have a parent div with slimscroll enabled, inside this div i have a input element which is a jquery combo box.(look at the screenshot)
[jquery combo box scroll issue with slim scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L519q.png)

When I click on combo box, it popups all the list items with vertical scrollbar but when i do mouse scroll its scrolling the parent div not the combo box list.

Here is the sample jsfiddle link 
    [with nested scroll issue with slimscroll][2]

Thanks in advance

```
   [2]: http://jsfiddle.net/ZE8HK/41/
```

Comment: Are u trying in a mobile?

Comment: No.I am trying in desktop browsers

Comment: I think the slim scroll jquery and auto complete jquery conflict with each other in position concept. change the position for autocomplete and check

Comment: Can you make fiddle your code so that we can check what may be the issue\